# How to erase an element in boost unordered_map by local_iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, hashtable, unordered-map

I am using C++ boost `unordered_map` hash table.
I can use `local_iterator` to traverse specific bucket.
Now, I want to erase some elements in this bucket.

```
ShmHashMap::local_iterator it = hash_table_->begin(bucket_idx);
while(it != hash_table_->end(bucket_idx)) {
    if(it->second >= now_time) {
        it++;
        continue;
    }
    hash_table_->erase(it);// this usage is not supported
    // although I can `hash_table_->erase(it->first)`, this usage is inefficient
    it++;
}
```

So, is there some way to erase element by `local_iterator`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `boost::unordered_map::erase` works in the same way as `std::unordered_map::erase`, then the sequence:

```
hash_table_->erase(it);
it++;
```

invokes undefined behaviour because `erase` invalidates `it`.

You can however do:

```
it = hash_table_->erase(it);
```

because `erase` returns the iterator following the one deleted.